# javascript conditionals not going to second statement

Tags: javascript

I just finished learning the basics of javascript so I'm working on a practice project that gets a credit card number, and it will tell you if its valid and what type of card it is. The problem I am having is when an array of the card number is passed in the function, it only checks the first if statement, which is mastercard. I am not sure why it isn't it going to the second if statement. Here is my code:

```
let cardType;

function getCreditCardNum(num) {
  let cardTypeAmexMasterCard = num.slice(0,2);

  if(cardTypeAmexMasterCard >= 51 || cardTypeAmexMasterCard <= 55) {
    cardType = "MasterCard";
  }
  else if(cardTypeAmexMasterCard == 34 || cardTypeAmexMasterCard == 37) {
    cardType = "American Express";
  }
  else {
    cardType = "INVALID CARD TYPE"
  }
  console.log(`Card Type is ${cardType}`);
}

let cardArray = [344234324];
getCreditCardNum(cardArray);
```

// consoles out mastercard instead of american express

Comment: If it outputs "MasterCard" then the first `if` condition is `true`.  So it's not going to go to any other condition in that `if` chain.  Once it finds a `true` one, it just uses that one.  That's how `if` and `else` work.

Comment: You are comparing array to number. Logic not making a lot of sense either. Why would a card number ever be an array?

Comment: Note that the conditions in your `else if` would also be satisfied by your first `if`.  So under no logical condition would your `else if` *ever* be executed.  (Hint: Both 34 and 37 are less than 55.)  Edit: In fact, wouldn't *every possible number* satisfy your first `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of errors,

- `.slice()` expects Array or String (in your specific case). Than you need back a `Number`
- You're passing the whole array into your function `getCreditCardNum(cardArray);` instead you should look for the `[0]`*th* key
- when checking for a **range** use `&&`

```js
function getCreditCardNum(num) {

  let nn =  Number( num.toString().slice(0,2) );
  
  if(nn >= 51 && nn <= 55) {
    cardType = "MasterCard";
  }
  else if(nn == 34 || nn == 37) {
    cardType = "American Express";
  }
  else {
    cardType = "INVALID CARD TYPE"
  }
  console.log(`Card Type is ${cardType}`);
}

let cardArray = [344234324];
getCreditCardNum( cardArray[0] );
```

How I'd do that:

```js
function getCreditCardType( val ) { // we're returning a TYPE so getCreditCardType

  const num =  +val.substr(0,2);  // Use substr. Use const, value will not change.
  let type = "INVALID CARD TYPE"; // Yep. It's invalid :D

  if(num >= 51 && num <= 55) {
    type = "MasterCard";
  } else if(num === 34 || num === 37) { // No need to typechecking. Use ===
    type = "American Express";
  }
  
  return type; // Return the needed response
  
}

let cardNumber = "344234324"; // No array; use string, since inputs values give us strings anyways.
const cardType   = getCreditCardType( cardNumber );
// test HERE instead
console.log(`Card Type: ${cardType}`);
```

Comment: slice() is also an array prototype method, not exclusive to string

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function is likely to be causing you problems, is that once an `if` statement is 'true' it only runs the code in that block.

So if the first `if` block is 'true' then you're not going to run the other checks. On top of this, your first statement will be true if the first two numbers are less than 55 `cardTypeAmexMasterCard <= 55`. It will also return true if the number is greater than 51, so as long as a number gets passed in, it will always return true, and the rest of your 'if else' statement won't run.

Your first if statement needs perform an AND check

```
if(cardTypeAmexMasterCard >= 51 && cardTypeAmexMasterCard <= 55)
```

This will stop it from always returning true.

Another issue with your code is that it is not passing a correct 2 digit number through, you are performing `slice(0,2)` on an array with only one element - this will always return the entire element.

Try accepting a number

```
let cardArray = 344234324;
getCreditCardNum(cardArray);

// then change this
let cardTypeAmexMasterCard = parseInt(num.toString().slice(0,2), 10);
```

This will give you a 2 digit number to work with.

Answer (score 0):

the parameter num  contains only one value. console log cardTypeAmexMasterCard and u will see what am saying. and your if statement is wrong too should be an and statement like &&.

Answer (score -2):

Here is one of your problems:

```
if(cardTypeAmexMasterCard >= 51 || cardTypeAmexMasterCard <= 55) {
    cardType = "MasterCard";
}
```

You should use AND instead of OR in your statement.